# How can I install OpenOffice in Ubuntu MATE 64bit?

Tags: openoffice.org

I've followed this tutorial which does not work for me. :https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=LFK3qiA5l6c
I'd like to use OpenOffice instead of libre office.

Comment: Could you please explain exactly what you mean by "... does not work for me"? What is not working?

Answer (score 0):

To install OpenOffice 4.1.1 on a 64 bit Ubuntu machine:

Remove the previously installed versions of either openoffice and libreoffice:

```
sudo apt-get remove libreoffice* openoffice*

sudo apt-get autoremove
```

Download, extract and install the deb package:

```
wget sourceforge.net/projects/openofficeorg.mirror/files/4.1.1/binaries/en-GB/Apache_OpenOffice_4.1.1_Linux_x86-64_install-deb_en-GB.tar.gz

tar -xzvf Apache_OpenOffice_4.1.1_Linux_x86-64_install-deb_en-GB.tar.gz

cd en-GB/DEBS

sudo dpkg -i *.deb

cd desktop-integration

sudo dpkg -i *.deb
```